# Containerization of a python code with stanfordnlp that uses gpu

Tags: python, docker, stanford-nlp

I would like to docker containerize my python script that uses gpu. The reason of containerization is that i am trying to run this code in a server that has python3.5 installed but stanfordnlp needs python3.6+.

So my approach is to create a container that uses the latest python image, run the python script that will use the nvidia gpu.

Below is a snippet of the python code where it imports the stanfordnlp for lemmatization technique

```
import stanfordnlp
import pandas as pd
import string

stanfordnlp.download('en')
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(processors='tokenize,mwt,lemma,pos', use_gpu=True)
```

As you can see I have explicitly typed use_gpu=True although that is True by default according to this [link](http://%20https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/pipeline.html#usage)

Next I have written a Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY lemmatizer.py ./
COPY eng_wikipedia_2016_1M-sentences.txt ./
RUN pip install stanfordnlp pandas
CMD [ "python" , "./lemmatizer.py" ]
```

When I build and then run the Dockerfile using the following commands according to the guides in this [link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) to use the gpu services when creating and deploying the container.

```
nvidia-docker build -t pylemm-gpu .
docker run -it --gpus all pylemm-gpu
```

After performing all the steps discussed above, I am still getting the message that my container is using cpu instead of gpu. I would really appreciate a guide and/or links to setup my container properly so that it can use the gpu.

p.s. I have tried the Usage part in the [link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) and checked that my server has 3 gpus.

Comment: Have you installed the cuda-drivers in your server?

Comment: when i run this "docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi" it shows the gpus and cuda installed

Comment: I have created another container using docker run -it nvidia/cuda:10.0-base and then checked nvidia-smi for cuda and nvidia drivers. Then i manually installed python, python3-pip, copied my files(lemmatizer.py & eng_wikipedia_2016_1M-sentences.txt) to /home/app folder. After that I ran python3 lemmatizer.py. Still showing that it is using CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuda-drivers were installed as it was showing with the command

```
nvidia-smi
```

stanfordnlp uses pytorch therefore I pulled pytorch docker image and ran interactively. I imported torch and checked whether cuda was installed using

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

which was returning False.

Using the command below

```
torch.version.cuda
```

I checked the version of Cuda used in that image

Then I understood that the latest version of Cuda was being used in pytorch/pytorch:latest according to the [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility__table-toolkit-driver). In my server it was using Cuda version 10.0, therefore I searched for an older version of pytorch using Cuda version 10.0 (matches with my Cuda version) from this [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch/tags).

This solved my problem, stanfordnlp and stanza are both using GPU now.